# Merging files by rows

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, columns, join

Is it possible to copy the whole rows of `File1` in a new `File3` following the instruction given by `File2` by using a simple bash script using `sed` or `awk`?

```
File1: /*two or more columns*/
AC    456324
DC    689712
GH    123677
KL    236587

File2: /*one column*/
AC
DC

File3: 
AC    456324
DC    689712
```

I'm actually performing this using Python dictionaries and I wondered if you knew a simple way out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `grep`

```
grep -Ff File2 File1
```

With `awk`

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]++;next} a[$1]' File2 File1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`join`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join) to combine rows from two files by joining them where a particular column has the same value in both files. Note that the input files need to be sorted by the values in that column..

```
join File1 File2
```

If the files aren't sorted, in bash/ksh93/zsh:

```
join <(sort File1) <(sort File2)
```

Here the field to join is the one that contains `AC`, `DC`, etc. Here's an example if the field to join is column 3 in `File1` with column 2 in `File2`.

```
join -1 3 -2 2 <(sort -k3,3 File1) <(sort -k 2,2 File2)
```